# Using Docker and haproxy in order to load balance requests to multiple instances of embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, docker, haproxy, docker-compose

I am trying to use Docker and haproxy in order to loadbalance/roundrobin request to a number of embedded tomcats.

My current configuration is as follows:

**From docker-compose.yml**:

```
loadbalancer:
  image: haproxy
  links:
      - web
  ports:
      - "8080:8080"
web:
  build: ./web
```

**From ./web/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM java:8
ADD ./bignibou-server-1.0.jar /app/bignibou-server-1.0.jar
ADD ./spring-cloud.properties /app/spring-cloud.properties
ENV SPRING_CLOUD_PROPERTIESFILE=/app/spring-cloud.properties
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=cloud
ENV SPRING_CLOUD_APP_NAME=bignibou
ENV CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@192.168.1.12:3306/bignibou_dev
ENV REDISCLOUD_URL=redis://dummy:dummy@192.168.1.12:6379
ENV DYNO=dummy
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/app/bignibou-server-1.0.jar" ]
```

When I do a docker-compose scale web=2 followed by a docker-compose up, I see both tomcat starting but then I am unable to access them through a browser...

Can anyone please advise on how to access my load balance app? I have tried:

- 172.17.42.1:8080
- 172.17.42.1:80

to no avail (where 172.17.42.1 is my docker ip).

Do I need to further configure haproxy?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to configure HAProxy, providing info on the backend servers and the load balancing algorithm to use. Just starting a container using the haproxy image is not sufficient.

You will need a Dockerfile to use the haproxy image and copy your specific haproxy configuration file to the image:
You can refer to the instructions in the official haproxy image page:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/

How to setup load balancing using HAProxy: https://serversforhackers.com/load-balancing-with-haproxy

I have written a blog on a sample docker worflow with Nginx, Node and Redis. It describes how to load balance node servers with nginx:
http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/

Conceptually it is the same as HAProxy balancing tomcat servers. But the configuration structure will vary. Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to modify your iptable rules for port 8080. Couple of things you can check. netstat -anp | grep 8080 to see if your app is infact listening on that port. You can also run tcpdump on host and within the container to see if you are getting the packets.